# Can I modify field type in serializer for ModelSerializers?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have model like:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    profile_picture = ImageField(upload_to=settings.MEDIA_ROOT, blank=True)
```

I have serializers:

```
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
```

In the serializers, I want to modify profile_picture field time to something else. Is that possible? how?

Comment: profile_picture field time?

Comment: Yes, it is field name. See the Profile model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By specifying the [source](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#core-arguments) parameter, you can rename fields from your model to anything you would like.

```
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    some_other_name = serializers.ImageField(source='profile_picture')

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('some_other_name',)
```

Comment: hay Mark, thanks for your answer, so it is source param. I tested